# GetQueuedCompletionStatus continues to select events on closed sockets

Tags: c++, winsock, iocp

IOCP server works with WebSocket connections. When the browser sends a close frame, the server `delete`s this client, the `closesocket` function is calling in client's object destructor. But even after the socket was closed, the `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` function continues to select events from this socket. Of course the result is `false` and 0 bytes transferred, but Client ptr and `OVERLAPPED` ptr are not NULL, and `GetLastError` returns 1236 (ERROR_CONNECTION_ABORTED)... so yeah, it is aborted, and the `closesocket` was called... But why it is still here??? And how to stop receiving this "useless" events? I can call `continue` in thead's loop, but it will waste CPU time if the function will select this removed client forever.

Here is the part of worker thread's loop:

```
while(WAIT_OBJECT_0 != WaitForSingleObject(EventShutdown, 0)){
    DWORD BytesTransfered = 0;
    OVERLAPPED *asyncinfo = nullptr;
    client *Client = nullptr;
    BOOL QCS = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(hIOCP, &BytesTransfered, (PULONG_PTR)&Client, &asyncinfo, INFINITE);
    if(!Client ) break;

    switch( QCS * (BytesTransfered > 0) * Client->OpCode() ){
        case OP_TYPE_RECV:{
        .....
            switch( recv_buf[0] &0xFF ){
            ....
                case FIN_CLOSE:
                    printf("FIN_CLOSE on client %u\n", Client->Socket());
                default:{
                    RemoveClient(Client);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        case OP_TYPE_SEND:{
        ...
        }
        default:{
            printf("Client %u (%lu bytes transferred, QCS is %d)\n", Client->Socket(), BytesTransfered, QCS);
            break;
        }
```

Client's destructor:

```
client::~client(){
    while(!HasOverlappedIoCompleted(&asyncinfo)) Sleep(0);
    closesocket(socket);
    if( a_ctx ) delete a_ctx;
    if( q_ctx ) delete q_ctx;
    delete [] data_buffer;
    printf("Client %u deleted\n", socket);
}
```

... and the server's log:

> Client 296 from 127.0.0.1 (agent 1987)
>  Client 308 from 127.0.0.1
>   (supervisor)
>  Client 324 from 127.0.0.1 (supervisor)
>  TOTAL: 3
>   client(s)
>  Sending 33278 bytes to 324
>  Send finished for 324
>   Send finished for 308
>  Sending 40529 bytes to 324
>  Send finished
>   for 324
>  Sending 41128 bytes to 324
>  Send finished for 324
>   Sending 40430 bytes to 324
>  Send finished for 324
>  FIN_CLOSE on
>   client 324
>  Client 324 deleted
>  Client 324 (0 bytes transferred,
>   QCS is 0)
>  Client 324 (0 bytes transferred, QCS is 0)
>  Client
>   324 (0 bytes transferred, QCS is 0)
>  Client 324 (0 bytes
>   transferred, QCS is 0)
>  Client 324 (0 bytes transferred, QCS is
>   0)

See that "*324 (0 bytes transferred, QCS is 0)*"? Socket 324 closed. Why it happens after destructor's message "*Client 324 deleted*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you've included enough code to get a complete picture, but this line looks suspect:

```
switch( QCS * (BytesTransfered > 0) * Client->OpCode() ){
```

This is problematic for a couple of reasons.  First, `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` is not guaranteed to return 1 on success.  MSDN promises only that it will return nonzero.  Relying on a specific value for the success case is therefore risky.  Second, you have no way to distinguish between a failed call and a successful call that returns 0 bytes.  You should really separate your logic for managing the dequeue and for dispatching particular I/O events.  This will make your code easier to understand and maintain.

You must also remember that there are two sides to every socket.  There are the structures and socket handle you associate with it in user space, and then there are kernel objects that manage the low level details.  Just because you close your handle on the user side does not mean that the kernel objects go away.  Kernel objects are referenced counted and will generally linger on until all I/O involving those objects is complete.

That's why you can still get I/O notifications for a socket after it has been "destroyed" from your program's point of view.  With sockets in particular, the shut down sequence will take place *after* you have closed your handle (because you did not explicitly shut down the socket before then).

Instead of destroying your Client object in response to a specific message, just close the socket handle and clean up your other structures in response to the abort notification.  You might also consider doing a graceful disconnect rather than aborting the connection.

Comment: When I close connection on C++ client, I'm getting error code 64 on server (ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED) and all operations ends. But the browser won't close its sockets, so the connection descriptor stays in kernel. It is strange... I need to clear this descriptor somehow. If it happens in a singlethreaded server, I'm afraid to think what will be when I'll add some threads ))

Comment: Indeed! I read about the closesocket function - it does not mean that the events associated with it will stop. So I just need to ignore these events?

Comment: Possibly, but the fact that you apparently get multiple events for a single close is concerning.  Like I said, I think some details are missing from the question.

Comment: I also found the reason why the connection does not close from both sides. According to WebSocket specification, the browser waits for echo-close from server and don't terminates the connection instantly. )